# MEGAsync with mega-cmd: How can I initiate syncing from command line?

Tags: synchronization, file-management, cloud

I'm using MEGAsync from [mega.nz](https://mega.nz).

Recently, I've encountered a bunch of problems with the syncing software. One of those problems, was that it seems to have trouble syncing (or scanning?) files that haven't been synced for quite a while. I recently booted a laptop I haven't used for a month or so, and syncing with the regular gui client doesn't really work.

So, I tried to "manually" sync with [mega-cmd](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd), but I'm having problems with it too.

In the graphical client I have a local directory configured for syncing: `/home/polemon/MEGA`.
The MEGA directory synced there is `/` (root).

However when I log in with `mega-cmd`, I can't see this directory being set up for syncing, running `mega-sync` with no arguments, doesn't return any configured directories, which is odd, because I do have those configured with the gui client.

Apparently, the configuration of the gui client doesn't carry over to the command line client. When running `mega-sync -r MEGA` it simply returns an error message, saying the sync can't be found.

The MEGAcmd "documentation" is very lackluster, and doesn't go into details working with the gui application (which is the official MEGA client) and the command line interface.

In my gui settings, in the "Sync" tab, I have one *folder* configured. This setup is equal over all my Linux and Windows devices, of which there are several (some of which are in VMs):

> *Local folder*: `MEGA`; *MEGA folder*: `/`

This one line is one line is ticked, so that syncing is active.

I'm under the impression, that I'd have to add this folder for syncing using the command line interface with: `mega-sync /home/polemon/MEGA /` or similar but as I said the documentation doesn't go into detail, and I don't want to damage my synchronization setup.

How can I use the command line `mega-*` commands for syncing into the already set-up configuration I did with the (official) gui client?

Comment: I'm convinced you can't use both at the same time

Comment: @ugjka well, even though the GUI client is "stuck" I can still download via command line from the MEGA repo, and view the online tree, etc. I really don't know, but I also don't want to mess it up…